# formula for 2 conditions joined by AND to return 1 or 0 as a result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to combine 2 search conditions within 2 particular cells for it to show result as 1 for both criteria met, or 0 for not

I ned to search for "BDAD" in column J which at the same time has "tier 2" in same row in column X. If condition is met I want "1" in that row in column AC and "0" if condition not met. Is this possible at all?

| Column J | Column X | Column AC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BDAD,CTAD,BULD | Tier 2 | 1 |
| BDAD,CTAD,BULD | tier 1 | 0 |
| CTAD,BULD | tier 2 | 0 |

I was hoping =IF9ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BDAD",J2)(SEARCH("Tier 2",X2)),"1","0") would work but I'm not getting anywhere...

Comment: Are you sure you're just in need to search for "BDAD", not one of or all of the separated strings in Column J?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option w/o using `AND`:

```
=--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BDAD",J2)+SEARCH("Tier 2",X2))
```

[image]

Another option is `COUNTIFS` with wildcards:

```
=COUNTIFS(J2,"*BDAD*",X2,"*Tier 2*")
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked brilliantly! I used the COUNTIFS one you recommended. Just thinking about an alternative, would there be an option to have result show "1" if criteria met and empty cell if not met?

Comment: Many options, such as `=IFERROR(1/1/COUNTIFS(J2,"*BDAD*",X2,"*Tier 2*"),"")`, or `=LET(x,COUNTIFS(J2,"*BDAD*",X2,"*Tier 2*"),IF(x=0,"",x))` if your version of Excel supports `LET`.